# i need to know why SCI always end being 0

Tags: python

I am trying to make a demonstration of montecarlo method just mathematically
but i am always getting 0.

I already tried putting sci= sci+1,

```
import random
import math
import time
print("generando")
sci=0
for i in range(30):
 x = random.random()
 y = random.random()
 if (x<x*x)and(y<=y*y) :#probably imposible to reach(?)
  sci += 1 #probably the error
 time.sleep(0.001)
scu=i
r=(4*sci)/scu
```

It actually needs to give a number near pi, it's more accurate when you increase the range in the for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) for `random.random`:

> Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0).

A number `x` within this range is **greater** than itself squared, i.e. `x <= x*x` will never be satisfied, as you correctly guessed.

A diagram to illustrate this:

[image]

This is likely a typo on your behalf. The correct formula to use for this problem is:

```
x*x + y*y <= 1.0    # random point falls within unit circle
```